# Finding the inverse modulo . $7^{-2}\pmod {11}$ and $7^{-3}\pmod {11}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

$7^{-1}\pmod{11}$

the above can be found by

$7x\pmod{11}\equiv 1$ and $x=8$

now i am confused on how to find $7^{-2}\pmod{11}$ and  $7^{-3}\pmod{11}$ .

Comment: oh so its $7^{-2}\pmod {11}\equiv 9$ ?

Comment: Indeed. It took me more than it should have to verify $64\equiv 9$ mod $11$ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ 7^{-2} \equiv (7^{-1})^2\ $ since $\ 7x\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 7^2 x^2\equiv 1.\,$

Comment: so can i substitute like $7^{-2}\equiv (7^{-1})^2\equiv(8)^2\\\equiv 64 \equiv 9 \pmod {11}$ ?

Comment: @RK Yes, $\ \color{#c00}{7^{-1}\equiv 8}\,\Rightarrow\, (\color{#c00}{7^{-1}})^2\equiv \color{#c00}8^2\ $ by the $ $  [Congruence Power Rule.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $ $ Similarly for $\ 7^{-3}\ \ $

Comment: and similarly for 
$7^{-3} \equiv 7^{-2}\cdot 7^{-1}\\
\equiv 9\times 8 \equiv 72 \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$

Comment: @RK Yes, done smartly by the [Congruence Product Rule.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)